# Making infinite loop using iCarousel

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, icarousel

Is it possible to configure that my iCarousel carousel will scroll the items with infinite loops?

I haven't found something like that and I need it,

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Yup, this is easy to do in iCarousel:

```
- (CGFloat)carousel:(iCarousel *)carousel valueForOption:(iCarouselOption)option withDefault:(CGFloat)value {
    switch (option) {
        case iCarouselOptionWrap:
            return YES;
    }

    return value;
}
```

Comment: I apologise – you're absolutely correct! I'll update my answer momentarily.

Comment: That's works now but I'm getting this issue message:

`enumeration values not handled in switch: 'iCarouselOptionShowBackfaces', 'iCarouselOptionOffsetMultiplier', 'iCarouselOptionVisibleItems'...`

Comment: You can add a `default` case that returns `value` if you want.

Answer (score 13):

If you are looking for solution in swift:

```
func carousel(carousel: iCarousel, valueForOption option: iCarouselOption, withDefault value: CGFloat) -> CGFloat
{
    switch (option)
    {
    case .Wrap:
        return 1

    default:
        return value
    }
}
```